# '#' in JSON that is used as $AJAX url parameter issue

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

The following JQuery ajax call works fine.
It is passing a Json string as a parameter.
As I say this works fine.
However if LoadFileSeperator = '#' the JSON parameter is truncated when received in AJAXSettingsUpdate on the server.

How can I encode LoadFileSeperator  so that whatever value it is will not truncate the JSON?

```
var jsonQuery = '{"LoadFileSeperator":"' + LoadFileSeperator + '",' +
    '"MakeUpperCase":"' + MakeUpperCase + '",' +
    '"PreAdviceGate":"' + PreAdviceGate + '",' +
    '"PreAdviceRail":"' + PreAdviceRail + '",' +
    '"PreAdviceBirth":"' + PreAdviceBirth + '"' +
    '}';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Admin/AJAXSettingsUpdate?jsonstr=" + jsonQuery,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result === "SUCCESS") {
            TypeUpdateSuccess("Updated");
        } else {
            TypeUpdateFail("Failure");
        }
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        showAlert("ERROR - " + e, "alert-danger");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not directly an answer to the question, but you can use `JSON.stringify` and pass it a JavaScript object (e.g. `{ LoadFileSeparator: ... }`) so that your code is more readable, as you don't have to construct your JSON string by hand.

Comment: ^^ always best not to construct JSON by hand. (Or XML, etc.)

Comment: Side note: The word "separator" is spelled "separator" (`a` after `p`), not "seperator".

Comment: Never ever use `async: false,` . It is a terrible practice and is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a `GET` operation and dumping the JSON into the URL completely un-encoded. Naturally, it gets cut off at the first invalid URI character (`#` is for introducing the fragment part of a URI).

You need to URI-encode anything you put in the URI:

```
url: "/Admin/AJAXSettingsUpdate?jsonstr=" + encodeURIComponent(jsonQuery)
```

---

Side note: As [John Weisz points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388189/in-json-that-is-used-as-ajax-url-parameter-issue/45388243?noredirect=1#comment77737222_45388189), constructing JSON strings by hand is error-prone and hard to read. Instead, construct the structure you want to send, and then use `JSON.stringify` to turn it into JSON:

```
var jsonQuery = JSON.stringify({
    "LoadFileSeperator": LoadFileSeperator, // Left original spelling here
    "MakeUpperCase": MakeUpperCase,
    "PreAdviceGate": PreAdviceGate,
    "PreAdviceRail": PreAdviceRail,
    "PreAdviceBirth": PreAdviceBirth
});
```

*(The quotes around the keys are optional in this case because all of those keys are valid identifier names, but it's harmless to include them in case you have keys that aren't valid identifier names.)*

In addition to improving readability, it ensures that all necessary escaping is done. (For instance, if any of those variables had contained a `"` or `\` or newline or any of a number of other characters, you'd've ended up with invalid JSON.)

And in ES2015, it would be even simpler because of inferred property names:

```
// REQUIRES ES2015 SUPPORT
let jsonQuery = JSON.stringify({
    LoadFileSeperator, // Left original spelling here
    MakeUpperCase,
    PreAdviceGate,
    PreAdviceRail,
    PreAdviceBirth
});
```

When you use inferred property names, the JavaScript engine infers (figures out) name of the property from the name of the variable you provide for its value.

---

Side note 2: If you can, send the JSON by POST, not GET:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Admin/AJAXSettingsUpdate",        // ***
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",         // ***
    data: jsonQuery,                         // ***
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        if (result === "SUCCESS") {
            TypeUpdateSuccess("Updated");
        }
        else {
            TypeUpdateFail("Failure");

        }
    },
    error: function(x, e) {
        showAlert("ERROR - " + e, "alert-danger");
    }
});
```

That would require changes at the server end, though.

Comment: Did not know about implied property names. Cool!

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Sorry, I should have called them "inferred" property names (that is, the JavaScript engine infers the name). :-)

Comment: No matter what they're called I didn't know about them. So pretty cool either way. Unfortunately my company deals in legacy which means most of the js I write has to work in ie8-10 so I'm not up to date as I'd really like to be. So always nice to learn something new.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: There's always transpiling with [Babel](http://babeljs.io) or similar. :-) (At Farsight, we also have to support older browsers for most of our stuff, so that's what we do.)